# SeqIO.parse python: Premature end of line during features table

Tags: python, parsing, bioinformatics

Anybody have this problem before? Any suggestion about the reason?

The script creates the files containing the genome sequences but it appears at the end of the process.

Line in my script

```
File "scripts/list_ncbi_download_genome_vs_02.py", line 97, in <module>
    SeqIO.write(SeqIO.parse(genbank_file, "genbank"), genome_file, "fasta")
```

Warnings that appear:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Bio/SeqIO/__init__.py", line 481, in write
    count = writer_class(fp).write_file(sequences)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Bio/SeqIO/Interfaces.py", line 209, in write_file
    count = self.write_records(records)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Bio/SeqIO/Interfaces.py", line 193, in write_records
    for record in records:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Bio/SeqIO/__init__.py", line 600, in parse
    for r in i:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Bio/GenBank/Scanner.py", line 478, in parse_records
    record = self.parse(handle, do_features)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Bio/GenBank/Scanner.py", line 462, in parse
    if self.feed(handle, consumer, do_features):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Bio/GenBank/Scanner.py", line 434, in feed
    self._feed_feature_table(consumer, self.parse_features(skip=False))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Bio/GenBank/Scanner.py", line 159, in parse_features
    raise ValueError("Premature end of line during features table")
```

I can live with this but it is not so beautiful to finish a process and it appears after.

The file is available for download at  https://github.com/felipelira/files_to_test/blob/master/GCF_000302915.1_Pav631_1.0_genomic.gbff

the block in my script that calls the command is:

```
## rename and move files to the output directory created in the command line:
genome_dict = {}
genome_list = []
for genbank_file in list_uncompressed:
    organism = genbank_file.split('/')[0]
    file_name = genbank_file.split('/')[-1]
    genome_file = organism +'_'+ file_name.split('_')[0] +'_'+ file_name.split('_')[1]+'.fna'
    genome_list.append(genome_file)
    genome_dict[genome_file.replace('.fna', '')] = organism
#print genome_dict
    print "Dealing with GenBank record %s" % genome_file
    SeqIO.write(SeqIO.parse(genbank_file, "genbank"), os.path.join(outdir, genome_file), "fasta")
    print "Genome saved %s" % genome_file
```

Comment: Its hard to say whats going on without your actual code and the genbank file but I get the impression your genbank file contains errors in its formating either after you did work with it or from the get go.

Comment: I downloaded the genome directly from NCBI FTP. I will include the file to download.

Comment: I downloaded your (one) file and when I run your code (the `SeqIO` part) with Biopython 1.68 and python3.5 or python2.7 I dont get any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved according to the recommendations in the post at biostars.org https://www.biostars.org/p/289314/#289407

Suggestions from Philipp Bayer:
https://www.biostars.org/u/4678/

> *Normally this should work (and it does on my system). Are you writing to the genbank_file in the script before that? Perhaps you haven't
>   closed the file handle yet so that writing to the file hasn't synced?*

and a.zielezinski:
https://www.biostars.org/u/4700/
from Bio import SeqIO

```
l = ['GCF_000302915.1_Pav631_1.0_genomic.gbff']
for genbank_file in l:
    fh = open(genbank_file)
    oh = open(genbank_file + '.fasta', 'w')
    for seq_record in SeqIO.parse(fh, 'genbank'):
        oh.write(seq_record.format('fasta'))
    oh.close()
    fh.close()
```